# Perl CGI syntax to control fonts in $cgi->radio_group()

Tags: perl, cgi, radio-group

After googling I can't locate many examples, and my trials aren't working to control the font/class of my radio button text.

```
 $cgi->radio_group( { -name => "product-$i", -values => \@p, -labels => \%labs,
               -default => $thisP , -labelattributes => { -class => 'element' } } )
```

produces this:

```
input name="product-3" value="1X" labelattributes="HASH(0xa9fd6cc)" type="radio"
```

which seems very odd since I followed the syntax in the CGI guide but obviously this is incorrect.

I also tried the same statement using -attributes instead of -labelattributes and it produces this

```
 $cgi->radio_group( { -name => "product-$i", -values => \@p, -labels => \%labs,
               -default => $thisP , -attributes => { -class => 'element' } } )
```

produces this:

```
input name="product-3" value="1X"  type="radio"
```

so this apparently does nothing.

Assistance is appreciated!

Comment: I suggest to NOT use `radio_group` function, rather create your own HTML as a based "template" and fill it with your own data using regular expression replacing. `radio_group` is quite old, and has not been updated (as far as I know) to the latest HTML standards

Comment: To add to what nrathaus said, I recommend using [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/) or something similar to generate your HTML. Write your own CSS stylesheet to control things like fonts.

Comment: Thank-You gentlemen, your insights are very helpful. I can easily make an exception and create what I need with raw HTML....

Answer (score 3):

Others have provided information into templating systems, which is preferred. With regards to your original problem, you could be using an outdated version of `CGI`. The issue you are experiencing cannot be replicated in versions later than **3.40**, when using the `-labelattributes` attribute.

```
use CGI;
print CGI->VERSION;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a templating library like [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/) is easier (both in terms of readability and maintainability) than generating HTML with CGI. Here is an example TT template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello, Template Toolkit!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Behold...buttons!</h1>
    [% FOREACH button = buttons %]
        <label>[% button.label %]<input type="radio" name="[% group_name %]"
                value="[% button.value %]" class="foo"/></label>
    [% END %]
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it's mostly plain-old HTML. The bits inside `[%` and `%]` are TT directives. You can use the template inside a CGI script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use Template;

my @buttons = (
    { value => 1, label => 'foo' },
    { value => 2, label => 'bar' },
);

my $template_vars = {
    group_name => 'foo',
    buttons    => \@buttons,
};

my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header;

my $tt = Template->new or die Template->error;    
$tt->process('foo.tt2', $template_vars) or die $tt->error;
```

Note that it's good practice to perform visual styling of elements using CSS stylesheets. That includes things like the font of the labels.

When you run the above CGI, the HTML output looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello, Template Toolkit!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Behold...buttons!</h1>

        <label>foo<input type="radio" name="foo"
                value="1" /></label>

        <label>bar<input type="radio" name="foo"
                value="2" /></label>

</body>
</html>
```